# Ground state of a particle in a ring - angular momentum is 0, but it is 'rotating' anyway?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Particle in 1D ring is a textbook problem, but there is one thing I don't understand - if the ground state is considered to have zero angular momentum, then its energy is also zero. And the wavefunction is constant in the ring. Isn't is unphysical? It means that there is equal probability to find particle in any position in the ring - so it's rotating, right? Even with $m=0$.

We can probably get rid of this state, and start with the first 'rotating' state with $m=\pm 1$, but in magnetic field, for example, we can't just ignore the $m=0$ state, because it's the only one that's not degenerate, and its existence is more or less confirmed by experiments.

And while 1D rings don't exist, the case of a finite width ring is absolutely the same. Both analytically solvable case and any other ring-like potential (see figure) have a ground state with zero angular momentum, but with 'stretched out' wavefunction maximum (it's a circle instead of a single point), so the particle effectively 'rotates'.

[image]

There is no such problem in most potentials. In a quantum box (rectangular, cylindrical or spherical) or in a hydrogen atom or in a harmonic oscillator there is only one maximum, so there is a single point where we can find the particle with most probability.

We can construct potentials with two or more 'central points', but the ring (or spherical layer which has the same property) is an extreme case, and I'm not sure what to think about its ground state.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what a ground state is and what it's properties are. The ground state (or states in the degenerate case) of a bound system is the eigenstate of the Hamiltonian with the lowest energy (energy being the eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian). If you are not used to the language used there, think *"the solution to the time-independent Schrödinger equation with the lowest energy"*. In any case, you don't expect that state to be an eigenstate of position, because for bound system position does not commute with the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @dmckee, thanks for clarification. So there is nothing strange about the probability density maximum being a circle instead of a point?

Comment: Nothing at all. I may understand your comment about s-state below rather better now. The ground state of the hydrogen atom *does not* have a definite position, not withstanding that the wave function has a single maximum. A definite position would be represented by a Dirac delta-function wave-function.

Comment: @dmckee, to be clear I did not say 'definite position' anywhere. I only meant the 'most probable position'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This state is not a eigenstate of either the position or the momentum operator. That means it doesn't have a definite value for either of those variables, so the question doesn't actually make sense.

The question you are asking is essentially a classical one, but this is a *quantum* system. The right answer is "the system has zero angular momentum, so the wavefunction has no angular dependence on time", and that is all you can say about it.

---

It is worth noting that the s-states of the hydrogen atom (or indeed any central potential) have this same property, and this is one of the several things we mean when we describe the sates as "orbitals" not "orbits".

Comment: You are not correct about s-states. You think about probability for a particle to be _at a certain distance_ from the nucleus, but I mean the probability or a particle to be _at a certain point in space_. For s-state in hydrogen atom there is only one maximum and it's at nucleus

Comment: You may have misunderstood me. The s-states have the property of having zero angular momentum and consequently no time dependence to their position-probability distribution. Moreover, the s-states with higher principle quantum number ($n$) have local position maxima at non-zero radius (though I believe the global maximum remains at the center).

Comment: Thank you, but I did not mean actual 'rotation' in classical sense. I only ask if this state can be considered ground state at all?